# Minimum of the sum of cosine between n vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, euclidean-geometry

I need to find the following minimum:

$\displaystyle{\min_{u_1,\dots,u_n}} \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j\neq i} \cos(\theta_{i,j}),$

where $u_1,\dots,u_n$ are unit vectors, and $\theta_{i,j}$ is the angle between $u_i$ and $u_j$.

For $n$ equidistant unit vectors, the cosine of the angle between any two of them would be $-\frac{1}{n-1}$. Thus, for a fixed $i$ we would get that $\sum_{j\neq i} \cos(\theta_{i,j}) = -1$, and the total sum would be equal to $-n$. I suspect this is the minimum of the sum above, but unable to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the minimum; here is a proof. Note $\cos(\theta_{i,j}) = \langle u_i, u_j \rangle$. So, letting $u = \sum_i u_i$, $\sum_i \sum_{j \not = i} \cos(\theta_{i,j}) = \sum_i \langle u_i, \sum_{j \not = i} u_j \rangle = \sum_i \langle u_i, u-u_i \rangle = \sum_i [\langle u_i,u \rangle-1] = \langle u,u \rangle - n$. Note that equality is attained if and only if $u=0$, which is the case for equidistant unit vectors.